# SQL Minus and lower/upper dont work together in Jdbc

Tags: spring, jdbc, hsqldb, tolower

i got a HSQLDB 2.2.9 and the following statement:

```
(SELECT lower(MyCol) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = ?)  
MINUS 
(SELECT lower(MyCol) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = ?)
```

And it works in my Squirrel. But when i execute this in my program which uses Jdbc i get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [(SELECT lower(MyCol) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = ? )  MINUS (SELECT lower(MyCol) FROM MyTable WHERE ID_CENTER = ?)]; Column not found: MyCol; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: MyCol
```

If i delete the lower() that statement works but its case sensitive which i want to eliminate here.

Can please someone tell me why i get this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This exception is not thrown by HSQLDB 2.2.9. If the column could not be found, the exception message would be in this form:

```
user lacks privilege or object not found: MYCOL
```

Please check your Spring data source settings.